# Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' python-django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, zip, file-system-storage

So the scenario here is, I have a endpoint that will take a zipfile, unzip it and save it to media dir for now. Here's the whole code for that

```
def get_filenames(path_for_zip):
    with ZipFile(path_for_zip, 'r') as zip:
        return zip.namelist()


class Upload(View):
    def post(self, request):

        context = {}

        upload_file = request.FILES['document']
        unzip_file = get_filenames(upload_file)
        for files in unzip_file:
            print(files)
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            fs.save('read.jpg', files)




        return render (request, 'toDo_app.html', context)
```

I am using `FileSystemStorage` as you can see. `ZipFile` is unzipping properly and i can see it in `print(files)` but the issue is at `FileSystemStorage` I guess, Its not getting saved and I get this error:

```
attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'read'.
```

Please point me out what did I do wrong and how should it be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@zeed namelist returns the name of the files in list i.e. string in the zip. While uploading read/open the file to buffer and upload

```
for files in unzip_file:
    print(files)
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    with open(files, "rb") as outstream:
        fs.save('read.jpg', outstream)
```

Comment: so namelist is basically a string. so it doesnt unzip and iterate through the files it just gives you the name of the file!

Comment: I think I am getting another error for that, as it is string, it doesn't really find the file in my uploaded file somehow. I am getting file not found error. Is there any way to not to get the name but the files like the zip.namelist